# Export SQL query output to a file in a scheduler job

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I need to export data to a csv file in a scheduler job. Here are the commands:

```
SPOOL "\\AServerName\Output\RMS_DataFileSizes.csv" REPLACE;
SELECT /*csv*/
  TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS "CurrentDTM",
  df.tablespace_name AS "Tablespace Name",
  SUBSTR(df.file_name,INSTR(df.file_name,'RMS_'),20) AS "File Name",
  Round(df.bytes/1073741824,2) AS "Size (GB)",
  decode(e.used_bytes,NULL,0,Round(e.used_bytes/1073741824,2)) AS "Used (GB)",
  decode(f.free_bytes,NULL,0,Round(f.free_bytes/1073741824,2)) AS "Free (GB)",
  decode(e.used_bytes,NULL,0,Round((e.used_bytes/df.bytes)*100,1)) AS "% Used"
FROM DBA_DATA_FILES DF,
     (SELECT file_id,sum(bytes) used_bytes FROM dba_extents GROUP by file_id) E,
     (SELECT sum(bytes) free_bytes,file_id FROM dba_free_space GROUP BY file_id) f
WHERE e.file_id (+) = df.file_id
  AND df.file_id  = f.file_id (+)
  AND df.tablespace_name = 'RMS_DATA'
ORDER BY df.tablespace_name,df.file_name;
SPOOL OFF;
```

When I make the "type of job" a "PL/SQL Block", it fails and I get the following error:

```
"ORA-06550: line 1, column 764:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "\\AServerName\Output\RMS_DataFileSizes.csv" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
ORA-06550: line 17, column 7:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "OFF" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "OFF" to continue.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Great idea, but I'd like to keep this as generic as possible as someone else may view or edit (eek!) what I have done. What I did end up doing is taking the entire code and putting it into a sql script file. Then I run it as an external (sqlplus) script. It actually dumps the output into an external file (export.csv). However, no matter what I do, whether using `SET SQLFORMAT CSV` or adding the `/*csv*/` shortcut, the output is never CSV. An other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not how you do that.
A `PLSQL_BLOCK` type job does not accept such commands. Use a `SQL_SCRIPT` type job. Example:

```
begin
  dbms_credential.create_credential(
    credential_name => 'oracle_user',
    username        => 'oracle',
    password        => 'Oracle123'
  );
end;
/

begin
  dbms_scheduler.create_job(
    job_name        => 'my_script_job',
    job_type        => 'sql_script',
    job_action      => 'conn bp/bp
set markup csv on
spool "/home/oracle/output.txt"
select tablespace_name, file_id, bytes/1024/1024 as size_mb from dba_data_files;
spool off',
    credential_name => 'oracle_user',
    enabled         => true,
    auto_drop       => false
  );
end;
/

$ cat /home/oracle/output.txt
SQL> select tablespace_name, file_id, bytes/1024/1024 as size_mb from dba_data_files;

"TABLESPACE_NAME","FILE_ID","SIZE_MB"
"SYSTEM",1,700
"SYSAUX",2,870
"UNDOTBS1",3,295
"USERS",4,112.5
"TEST",5,100
```

Keep in mind, `SET MARKUP CSV ON` is a 12.2 feature. It will not work with 12.1.
`/*csv*/` is a SQL Developer feature, that will also not work.

Comment: Thanks. The `MARKUP` hint fixed it. See my further comments below.

Answer (score 0):

How about a slightly different approach?

Put that code into a .SQL file, let's call it `p.sql`:

```
spool p.txt

SELECT /*csv*/
  TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS "CurrentDTM",
  df.tablespace_name AS "Tablespace Name",
  SUBSTR(df.file_name,INSTR(df.file_name,'RMS_'),20) AS "File Name",
  Round(df.bytes/1073741824,2) AS "Size (GB)",
  decode(e.used_bytes,NULL,0,Round(e.used_bytes/1073741824,2)) AS "Used (GB)",
  decode(f.free_bytes,NULL,0,Round(f.free_bytes/1073741824,2)) AS "Free (GB)",
  decode(e.used_bytes,NULL,0,Round((e.used_bytes/df.bytes)*100,1)) AS "% Used"
FROM DBA_DATA_FILES DF,
     (SELECT file_id,sum(bytes) used_bytes FROM dba_extents GROUP by file_id) E,
     (SELECT sum(bytes) free_bytes,file_id FROM dba_free_space GROUP BY file_id) f
WHERE e.file_id (+) = df.file_id
  AND df.file_id  = f.file_id (+)
  AND df.tablespace_name = 'RMS_DATA'
ORDER BY df.tablespace_name,df.file_name;

spool off
exit
```

---

I'm on MS Windows, so - create a .BAT file; let's call it `p.bat`:

```
sqlplus sys/pwd as sysdba @p.sql
```

---

Finally, use your operating system scheduling program (Task Manager on my Windows) and schedule `p.bat` to run as often as you want, e.g.

- let it run daily at 22:00
- action = Start a program (navigate to `p.bat`)
- optionally (I'd suggest you to use it), set "Start in" directory

Should work; at least, works for me.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up (sorta) doing. But, instead of running it in Windows Task Scheduler, I ran it out of the job as an external script. This was a big help, but the `MARKUP` hint that @Balazs-Papp handed out was exactly what I was missing. If I could have marked both as helpful answers I would have.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you made it work.